# Conditional join of tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, join, conditional-statements

Let's say I allow users to filter some data not necessarily shown in the UI.
I do not want to include a table that's not filtered on, the query is pretty huge and every bit of performance gain is more than welcome (personally I would go with pure SQL in these corner cases, but EF is prefered).

So basically it boils down to the following:

```
var listOfFilterProperties = { "C" };
var q = 
    from x in context.X
    where x.B = 'zzz'
    select new DataObject {
        prop1 = x.A,
        prop2 = listofFilterProperties.Contains("C")
        ? x.B.C
        : String.Empty
    }
```

Of course this example is very contrived, but the basic principle is the same.

If listOfFilterProperties doesn't contain a FirstName property everything is fine and dandy, but as soon as it contains it, everything goes down the crapper.
So I can probaby conclude this isn't the way to go.

Any idea how I should go about doing this?

Comment: I think you have removed to much of the original code, I assume the listOfProperties is really a list, because I am missing `new []` now it probably changes to a like instead of an `IN` which is probably not supported in E.F. Try getting the produced SQL and analyze that.

Comment: Yeah, it's a list of the names of properties filled by some external actor. It's just to convey the idea of using the ternary operator in a linq query like that. The rest of the code is just a lot of (left) joins and more properties in the select.